# Is code coverage already working for Swift?

Tags: swift, code-coverage, gcov, xcode6

I am trying to setup test code coverage for a Swift application on Xcode 6 Beta 4.
I was able to do so in the past using ObjectiveC with Xcode 5, however I think I had to call the `void __gcov_flush()` method, to trigger generation of the .gcda/.gcno files.
I set both properties for instrumentation and code coverage to `YES` for the app and test targets.
However after running the tests, when I look in:
DerivedData/some subfolders/i386 all I see are files of type:
.d,.dia,.o,.swiftmodule and so on, but nothing that indicates code coverage.

Therefore I have two questions:

1. Is code coverage expected to work for Swift using Xcode6 beta 4?
2. If yes and it is necessary to flush gcov first, how do I do that
   from Swift?

Thanks

Comment: Anyone got any insight into this? Is code coverage simply not possible in Xcode 6?

Answer (score 3):

Xcode 6 Beta 4 does not have code coverage for Swift working. There is an open Apple issue with id: 17450338 against it.

Comment: Could you add a link to the issue?

Comment: @Maxwell Apple's issue tracker (called Radar) is private, so unfortunately there's no way to link to the issue directly. The OpenRadar site allows anyone to replicate the issues they've reported to Apple, here's the relevant one: http://www.openradar.me/17450338

Comment: Do you know if it's sorted out in later versions yet?

Answer (score 2):

Code coverage for Swift is available in Xcode 7. You can turn it on in the test settings for your scheme, by ticking the checkbox labeled "Gather coverage data."

Note that Apple has introduced a new format for the coverage data, profdata files.

Links:

- [Xcode Overview: Using Code Coverage (Mac)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/CheckingCodeCoverage.html) (Apple docs)
- [Xcode Overview: Using Code Coverage (iOS)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/CheckingCodeCoverage.html) (Apple docs)
- [Leveraging Swift Code Coverage with Xcode 7](http://viteinfinite.com/2015/07/leveraging-swift-code-coverage-with-xcode-7/) (blog post, not mine)

Comment: if the 3rd one is your blog post, please say so, because it is a url to some unknown domain

Comment: No, it's not my blog post.

Answer (score 0):

It does not fixed in Xcode 6.3, see http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=6457429508227072