# Unit test: Is there ways to see code coverage for Swift?

Tags: ios, unit-testing, swift

I tried to find the ways but taking code coverage seems to be impossible so far. Does anybody know how to do it?

According to Apple's issue tracker, the issue was registered but the status did not change since last year.

[Is code coverage already working for Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25006983/is-code-coverage-already-working-for-swift)

Thanks,

Update:

> Swift doesn't seem to support coverage yet. by jonreid

https://github.com/jonreid/XcodeCoverage/issues/33

Comment: Is something new about this topic?

Comment: @emoleumassi I'm afraid not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with xcode7, apple will resolve this problem, see https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_7_0.html

Comment: Wow! Thank you for letting me know!

Comment: just click of this answer is useful. Thank